# How to use rfe object with function pickSizeTolerance in R package caret

Tags: feature-selection, caret, rms

I run `caret`'s recursive feature selection with randomForest. While running `rfe` function with method repeatedcv, I had parameter maximize = TRUE. Thus, optimal set of variables is decided based on the best RMSE metrics.

However, I would like to see the minimum "tolerable" set of predictor variables without rerunning rfe with parameter maximize = FALSE. It takes 24 hours to rerun my analysis.

Appearently, caret's function `pickSizeTolerance` does the trick, as is described on caret's webpage: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/featureselection.html

How to use the existing rfe object to get the "tolerable" set of variables?

Reproducible code:

```
library(caret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = iris[,4],
                           p = .66,
                           list = FALSE)
training <- iris[ inTrain,]
testing <- iris[-inTrain,]
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5,
               verbose = TRUE, returnResamp = "all")
rfProfile <- rfe(training[,-4], training[,4], sizes = c(2,3), rfeControl = ctrl, newdata = testing[,-4])
```

Object `rfProfile$resample` includes all the metrics, but how to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, functions `pickSizeTolerance` and `pickSizeBest` are well documented in `caret`'s ?rfFuncs

The above written reproducible code can be further used following the [documentation's example](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/nbFuncs) :

```
example <- data.frame(RMSE =rfProfile$results$RMSE, Variables = c(2:4))

## Percent Loss in performance (positive)
example$PctLoss <- (example$RMSE - min(example$RMSE))/min(example$RMSE)*100

xyplot(RMSE ~ Variables, data= example)
xyplot(PctLoss ~ Variables, data= example)

absoluteBest <- pickSizeBest(example, metric = "RMSE", maximize = FALSE)
within5Pct <- pickSizeTolerance(example, metric = "RMSE", maximize = FALSE)

cat("numerically optimal:",
    example$RMSE[absoluteBest],
        "RMSE in position",
        absoluteBest, "\n")
cat("Accepting a 1.5 pct loss:",
    example$RMSE[within5Pct],
"RMSE in position",
within5Pct, "\n")
```